# xubuntu light-locker: where is the configuration stored?

Tags: xubuntu, light-locker

My companies software stack for Linux includes some "security scripts" that check if the screensaver is configured according to our security policy. I am about to extend that script to handle light locker.

Step 1 will be to retrieve the current light-locker settings. So where can I find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo find / -name *light-locker*` on my xubuntu 14.04 install finds these entries: http://pastebin.com/JgTW10RV

The most promising option is the `light-locker-settings.py` which ends up pointing to the following files:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop
~/.config/autostart/light-locker.desktop
~/.config/autostart/screensaver-settings.desktop
```

The first one seems to be system wide settings, the second seems to be user settings, and the third seems to be for screensaver settings.

Comment: Thanks. A rather interesting concept: those desktop files are actually wrappers used to invoke programs. And in deed, the "Exec" lines in there do contain the numbers that define the behavior of light-locker!